# How to get data in .json file and apply condition on that

Tags: json

I am working on an application. I am creating a JSON file named `trades.json` and using that on another website.

My url is such

`http://mydomain.com/api/USD/trades.json?since=15054</p>`

How can I get the `since` value into that file? I have to send value that is greater than `since` value.

How can I do that? Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

If your URL points to a file resource that is already present on your server that you simply download, the URL query params make little sense.

If I understand well, you want to create/edit your file dynamically upon request parameters. For that purpose you need some kind of backend processing, e.g. a PHP engine.